# How to store/retrieve global variables in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

How can I store global variables and retrieve them with Sublime Text. I would like to use them for a build configuration. These variables would contain information such as (Debug, Release; Win32, Win64)

```
     {
         "shell_cmd": "gcc ${custom_variable}"
         "name": "Build",
     }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the variables of Build Systems of Sublime Text like [these](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html?highlight=variables#build-system-variables), but custom ones?

Comment: No custom variables that would be used in Build Systems.

Comment: You could take a look a [variants](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#variants). This is not exactly what you requested, but you could create a variant for `Debug - Win32`, `Release - Win64`, .... Alternatively you could create your own command and write it as `target` in the sublime-build file.

Comment: As target? How would that work?

Comment: @user6033608 Instead of using `cmd` or `shell_cmd` you write a [WindowCommand](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.WindowCommand) as plugin and use the name as `target`. In this plugin you can write arbitrary python code and access the sublime settings.
At the end you would call something like `subprocess.Popen(["gcc", custom_variable, view.file_name()])`. How would you want to set the custom variables? E.g. Project properties, view properties, comments in the view, ...